# Checking if an exe is 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: python, scons

I'm writing a python program that uses scons to build an `.exe` and then checks to see if it's a 64-bit or 32-bit. I tried `platform.architecture(test1.exe)`, but the problem is when I give a 32-bit exe, it says it's a 64-bit.

I tried using `dumpbin` but the output is huge, so I used this `dumpin /HEADERS test.exe |find "machine"`. The problem is I can't use python to execute this command. When I use `subprocess.call(['dumpbin /HEADERS test2.exe |find "machine"'])`, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_scons.py", line 66, in <module>
    print "Architecture of the compiled program is ",subprocess.call(["dumpbin /HEADERS test2.exe |find ""machine" ])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: The error is a problem of the path, it cant find the executable/script.

Comment: If you are launching SCons to build the executable, why do you need to know if its 32/64 bits? I would think you would control that in SCons with build the options you pass to it.

Comment: @Brady: it cannot find the binary named `'dumpbin /HEADERS test2.exe |find "machine"'`, no..

Comment: For Python3, please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999530/checking-if-an-executable-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-with-a-python3-script-on-windows-l/61999691 and look for the answer from @L3viathan. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify all the arguments separately:

```
subprocess.call(['dumpbin', '/HEADERS', 'test2.exe', '|', 'find', '"machine"'])
```

You could grep through the output in python just fine too.

As an aside: [`platform.architecture()`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.architecture) tells you the current platform architecture you are running scons *on*, nothing about the binaries you are producing or even how the python version was compiled. It *can* provide this info for other binaries, but *only if the executable points to the Python interpreter*, and probably not on Windows as there is no equivalent of the `file` command present there.

Comment: Are you sure that subprocess allows variable arguments instead of a list? `subprocess.call('ls, '-a')` fails for me (Python 2.7.2), while `subprocess.call(['ls', '-a'])` works as expected.

Comment: Nice answer to the problem about executing dumpbin, but I wonder about the OP's need to do so. Seems like the 32/64 bitness should be controlled by the build process and it shouldnt need to be queried after launching the build.

Comment: @Brady: perhaps; I never use scons myself, or build windows binaries.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. What I entered was `platform.architecture(test1.exe)`, I read some where that will give you the architecture of the .exe file.

@brady This is a diagnostic  and I was told to add this feature in.

Comment: @cyberbemon: the documentation for that function states that only works for python executables, and only on UNIX-like platforms.

Comment: @Martijn, I just tried it on 32-bit and 64-bit C binaries of the same program (both for a *NIX system), and it worked as expected. And cyberbemon, I stand corrected. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @martijin It's printing out wall of text!, guess I'll just search through it and print the architecture separately

also this error at the end `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '|'
 1104`

Comment: @cyberbemon: I guess that the subprocess shell used on Windows doesn't know about pipes..

Comment: found a way to get remove the wall of text, `log = subprocess.check_output(['dumpbin', '/HEADERS', 'test2.exe', '|', 'find', '"machine"'])`, then searched what I Want and printed it out ;)

Comment: For Python3, please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999530/checking-if-an-executable-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-with-a-python3-script-on-windows-l/61999691 and look for the answer from @L3viathan. It works like a charm!