# Checking if an executable is 32-bit or 64-bit with a python3 script on Windows/Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, 32bit-64bit

I'm writing software in Python3 (more specifically: `Python 3.8.1`). At some point, the software needs to check if some arbitrary executable is 64-bit or 32-bit. After some research, I found the following post:

[Checking if an exe is 32 bit or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097535/checking-if-an-exe-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

In this post, the following solution is offered:

```py
subprocess.call(['dumpbin', '/HEADERS', 'test2.exe', '|', 'find', '"machine"'])
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in `Python 3.8.1`. That post is almost 8 years old and dates back to the `Python 2.x` days.

How can I test for 64-bitness from within `Python 3.x`? I need a solution for both Linux and Windows 10.

> **EDITS :**
>   *Windows-related note:*
>   Apparently the `DumpBin` solution (see [Checking if an exe is 32 bit or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097535/checking-if-an-exe-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) post) requires Visual Studio to be installed. That's a no-no for me. My Python3 software should run on any Windows 10 computer.
>
> *Linux-related note:*
>   On Linux, I don't neet to test PE format executables. Just Linux executables are fine.

Comment: DumpBin is a Visual Studio thing, from memory. That means it won't be generally available on all Windows installs, and *certainly* not under Linux.

Comment: In the solution for Linux, do you want to also examine programs in the PE format (i.e. windows binaries)? Or do you want to test linux binaries for their 64-bit-ness?

Comment: @paxdiablo => Thanks for the info. I didn't know this. Is there some solution that just uses generally available things on Windows?

L3viathan => on Linux I just need to test linux binaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detecting the 64-bitness of ELF binaries (i.e. Linux) is easy, because it's always at the same place in the header:

```
def is_64bit_elf(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        return f.read(5)[-1] == 2
```

I don't have a Windows system, so I can't test this, but this might work on Windows:

```
def is_64bit_pe(filename):
    import win32file
    return win32file.GetBinaryType(filename) == 6
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked from the first try! I tested about 6 executables from which I know the bitness, and the results are all perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: You might also want to check that they're executables as well. From memory, the first three characters in Linux-land should be `ELF` and the first two in Windows-world should be `MZ`.

Comment: These are excellent answers ;) In order to have win32file module, one needs to install `pywin32` via pip ;) Thank you, made my day for bitness detection in my exe file signing library